# Transferring certain messages from a log to another

Tags: python, logfiles

I need to read a file, then take certain lines of the file, then write the lines I need to another file. I'm kinda stuck and can't seem to find a solution. The lines that need to be taken from `bi_server1-diagnostic.log` need to have the word `biserviceadministration` in them. Then they can be written onto the log file SAC report. This is what I have so far; I get the feeling it is wrong though:

```
with open('bi_server1-diagnostic.log', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if 'biserviceadministration' in line:
            with open ('SAC Report.log', 'w') as outfile:
                outfile.write
```

Comment: You don't have to rely on your feeling. You can try executing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close. What was your problem? I would use the full paths for the files but it can also be done like that.

```
with open('bi_server1-diagnostic.log', 'r') as infile:
    with open ('SAC Report.log', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            if 'biserviceadministration' in line:
                outfile.write(line)
                #print(line, file=outfile) alternatively
            else:
                continue
```

Comment: I went through several errors including stuff about I/O files being closed and i managed to fix them then i realised nothing was actually going into my log file at which point i got stuck and tried to fix for about an hour. i then decided to come here. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Please comment when down-voting.. I would honestly like to know what could be done better, what was not taken into account, etc..

Comment: I didn't down vote you :( I choose you as the answer

Comment: i was referring to whoever did, not you specifically.